# NVCPL.DLL in RunDLL can't be initiated on startup

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-installer, quicktime, dll

I got a new computer and installed Windows 8.
But everytime I start up I get this message:
(*Couldn't post the images because of my low reputation. But here is what they said*)

Was in Swedish, translated:

> **RunDLL**
>
> There was a problem with the start of NVCPL.DLL
>
> The initiation of a DLL-file failed

I have no idea what it does and how to fix it.

*This next part was solved using "Run as administrator (rookie mistake)*

I don't know if this will help but
I have got some more problems with DLL files. Here is an example:

> ** QuickTime for Windows**
>
> A problem has occurred with the windows-installer package. A DLL-file
>   which is needed for this installation couldn't be used. Contact
>   support or distributor.

Comment: Run an elevated command prompt and try `sfc /scannow`, let it complete, and reboot. If that doesn't help, reinstall the Nvidia graphics drivers and QuickTime. `nvcpl.dll` is the Nvidia graphics driver control panel.

Comment: Thank you, the sfc scan didn't work so uninstalled, and downloaded new drivers. So now it works smooth. The QuickTime installer dindn't work though. Maybe I should just download a new pack? I wish I had more reputation so I can vote up your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you do an upgrade or a clean install?

Do a clean install, I suspect you pulled in old Nvidia drivers that may not be compatable or propertly setup for Windows 8.